# AJAX unable to call function

Tags: ajax, jquery

it seems that my script is unable to call PHP functons in ajax_test.php. I am trying to achieve the call for php function when the dropdown box is changed. My html page is index.php. The code is below. Can anyone enlighten me?
 index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cm").change( 
function ()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    //code goes here
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            var test = $.ajax
            ({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_test.php",
            dataType: "json",               
            }).done(function(){
                document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            });
        }
     }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
});
});
</script>
<div>
<div id="box"><p>a</p></div>
<form>
<select id="cm">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>
```

ajax_test.php

```
<?php
function hey(){
    echo '<p>hey</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you included the libraries??

Comment: Use th simple way as told by deepak. if you have been able to include jquery

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery, you should stick to jquery functions.
Try replacing your change function with below code.

```
$("#cm").change( 
   function (){
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_test.php",
        dataType: "json"               
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#box").html(data);
        });
   }
 });
```

Also make sure, you are sending correct dataType. Check if the server is returning `application/json` for response type for the ajax call.

You not only have to define, but also call the function `hey()` in your php script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing with the libraries.
add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

before the script starts.
Here I am using 1.8.3, you can use latest one Just google around it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
You are trying to mix 2 ways to call ajax. I mean using XMLHttp request object & also jquery ajax. Try either one. I suggest you for jquery ajax. Tell me if you need any programming help.
```

-
Thanks